# A text is sent by socket non-stop, in a loop, I wanted it to be sent only once

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I wrote a code that just send a pre-established text. I got it, but the text is sent endlessly, non-stop, I wanted it to be sent only once. How do I do it please?

Server

```
from socket import *
host = gethostname()
port = 8889

print(f'HOST: {host} , PORT {port}')
serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind((host, port))
serv.listen(5)
while 1:
    con, adr = serv.accept()
    while 1:
        msg = con.recv(1024)
        print(msg.decode())
```

Client

```
from socket import *
host = gethostname()
port = 8889
cli = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
cli.connect((host, port))
while 1:
    msg = ("hi")
    cli.send(msg.encode())
```

[The result does not stop printing the hi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIHwO.png)

Comment: *"The result does not stop printing the hi"* - well, do you unterstand what your `while 1: ...` is doing? It creates an endless never stopping loop. I'm not sure what you intended to do with this statement, maybe something different or maybe you've just copied code from somewhere w/o understanding what it does.

Comment: I got a code that sends a text typed and placed to send a pre-established text, just lol I'm a beginner, sorry. I imagine that while 1, the code will run infinitely, but how do I stop it please?

Comment: So get rid of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while 1:` means: loop forever.
The client will loop forever sending a message, there is no need for `while 1:` in the client.

You might also want to remove the `while 1:` from server at line 9 as the server will never exit the following loop at line 11.

In case you want the while loop to stop looping you could check for a state of something, you could replace the `1` with a boolean operator (either true/1 or false/0). Here are some [Python boolean operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-boolean-operators-in-Python)